# Strange Behavior with Thread.Sleep in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, thread-sleep

Below is some simple code that uses Thread.Sleep to suspend execution, and Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds to find how long the thread actually slept.

```
Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
Dim elapsed_ms As Integer = 0

sw.Start()
While True
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
    elapsed_ms = CInt(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    Debug.WriteLine("Elapsed: " & elapsed_ms & " ms")
    sw.Restart()
End While
```

My question is: **occasionally, the debug print says that 0 ms have elapsed. How is this possible?** I am aware that Thread.Sleep(10) is not accurate, and that it normally sleeps for longer than 10 ms, but I thought that it was guaranteed to sleep a minimum of 10 ms.

Comment: Check  `Frequency` and `IsHighResolution` on the `StopWatch` to verify that you actually have a `StopWatch` with a high resolution timer on it.

Comment: Frequency is 2531513, which (I believe) means it should be accurate to ~half a microsecond. Either way, IsHighResolution field reads True.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this by creating a new blank console project, and pasting in your code.  I don't see any 0 ms lines, but I do see a lot of 9 ms ones, which shouldn't really be happening from what I understand.  What OS are you using, and is this the entirety of your code?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro, and no. The code posted is essentially being used simulate how far a motor has turned based on a constant velocity and the passage of time. There's also some GUI updating happening. The basic flow is sleep ->  measure time -> increment motor -> update GUI -> repeat. To my understanding, the Thread.Sleep along with the calculations and GUI update should ensure the stopwatch elapses at least some time. Edit: the bug manifests less than 1% of the time

Comment: The closest I can find to an answer is from the OS's [`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) function, which `Thread.Sleep` calls. "The system clock "ticks" at a constant rate. If dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time."

Comment: I have a vague recollection of reading somewhere that if the process is running on a multi-core system, and the OS moves from running it on one core to another between time measurements, the timer can return screwy results.  I'm having a hard time finding a source for that though, so I can't guarantee it is accurate.  You can try changing the process affinity to lock it down to one CPU from the task manager to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, that at least sounds like a reasonable explanation, thanks for the info (however dubious, lol ). If you happen to find it back, I would definitely be interested in reading it!

Answer (score 0):

I personally try to avoid using `Thread.Sleep` in my code for a variety of reasons but the irregularities that you are seeing is one of them.

So instead of calling `Thread.Sleep` I will calculate a timeout in the future for whatever increment you would have been sleeping for and then use a `while` loop that does nothing. So your main `While` loop would look like:

```
While True
    Dim l_TO As Date = Now.AddMilliseconds(10)
    While l_TO > Now
        'Do Nothing, 
        'Sometimes I will put a Thread.Sleep call in here but that's usually if the amount of time being waited is more than seconds. 
        'Mainly because a loop of this nature will chew up more processing power than you would expect.
        Thread.Sleep(1) 'Probably not need because of the short time that you are forcing the program to wait.
    End While
    elapsed_ms = CInt(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    Debug.WriteLine("Elapsed: " & elapsed_ms & " ms")
    sw.Restart()
End While
```

I know this doesn't explain why you are seeing weird behavior with `Thread.Sleep` But I thought it was worth mentioning that `Thread.Sleep` has a lot of downsides and can be avoided fairly easily.

Comment: I like the use of Date, but wouldn't this way use a lot more processing power than the sleep and stopwatch method? Edit: also, what value does the debug print generally show?

Comment: That's what I was getting at with the comments, but having the `Thread.Sleep(1)` in the loop will alleviate a lot of the processing power concerns. Unfortunately this means you are still relying on `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Just whipped up a quick test and it appears that I am receiving 9-11 ms being recorded in the output window. I was monitoring the task manager as well and the CPU usage was being recorded as 0 for its entire run time. I did not see any 0ms being recorded aside from the first logging line but I believe that was a bug in my 5 minute test app.